# What happens if you go below the minimum common mode voltage of a current sense amplifier?

Tags: operational-amplifier, current, amplifier, sensor, differential

This might be a simple one, but I can only seem to find information on going above the common mode voltage (V<sub>CM</sub>), not below it. Obviously going above the V<sub>CM</sub> upper limit will damage the device.

I'm looking at the ZXCT1080, which has a common mode voltage of 3V to 60V. **What happens if the V<sub>CM</sub> is below 3V?** Even if there is a differential voltage (i.e. current flowing through the shunt), will the output of the amplifier still just be 0V (or close to 0V considering any output voltage swing limitations)?
[image]

I've previously used the INA240, so I do know I can avoid this situation with a different device.

Comment: I would think it depends on the internal circuitry. A current sense camp can usually be just thought of as a differential amplifier with unusually high common mode rejection so most of the same behaviour should apply. Phase inversion, for example.

Comment: It'll turn into a death star.

Comment: The manufacturer is telling you *there be dragons* as @SpehroPefhany suggests. They don't want to characterize this region of operation, lest users depend on it in their designs. Would you want some future replacement part to perhaps behave differently?

Comment: So if I was to use this part, I should also measure the common mode voltage and not accept the current sensor input when it is below 3V?

Answer (score 3):

Judging by the Fig 11 graph, below about 3-5V (depending on temperature) typically, the output error starts to increase rapidly in the positive direction, so it may end up going completely high at somewhere around 2V or 2.5V.

That's just a guess, and it may do something else for very low inputs (but still > 0). There are no guarantees, if the datasheet was an early 16th century globe it might say "hic sunt dracones" (here be dragons).

[image]

Comment: Could what you're describing be because the differential amplifier is actually powered off the positive input (Fig.20: https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/ZXCT1080.pdf), so it would need to be above a threshold (3V) to power up properly?

Comment: It probably has more to do with a differential pair input with a current source in the sources and the respective threshold voltages on those MOSFETs.

Comment: * current sink..

Answer (score 2):

Being a high side differential current sense Op Amp driving a Nch FET I would expect below 3 V there will be insufficient Voltage to bias the gate and meet the CMRR spec then it will be voltage sensitive until it no longer is accurate.